# Compress a directory using LZ4 in C++

Tags: c++, directory, compression, archive, lz4

My objective is to compress a whole directory using LZ4. I have the code to compress a single file. So I iterated over directory and sub-directories and compressed every file with (.lz4) extension (Eg: filename.txt to filename.txt.lz4). The result I get is a directory containing the compressed files. But I want the output to be an archive file. I don't know which file extension the resultant folder should be archived (zip, tar). Also, how to do that in C++. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You make a compressed tar archive by doing just that: make that tar *first*, then compress it (this is nice because it exploits inter-file redundancy). A zip file compresses each file separately, then gloms those streams into a bigger file. However, I don't think it supports lz4 as a compression scheme (at least, Wikipedia doesn't seem to list it). Therefore, you're kinda hosed if you're lz4 compressing each file separately. [The tar format is pretty simple, though](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28computing%29).

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a tar file, which is an uncompressed archive of your files and directories, and then compress that with lz4. [libarchive](https://www.libarchive.org/) can help with the tar part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command line :

```
tar cvf - directory | lz4 - archive.tar.lz4
```

Regeneration will be

```
lz4 archive.tar.lz4 - | tar xvf -
```

Comment: I want to make the directory to .tar file in C++ code itself. Can you help me with that?

Comment: You could shell out a [`system()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) invocation from inside your C++ program. If that's not possible, then you will need to use relevant libraries directly, which is a whole different complexity. As suggested by Mark, libarchive would be a good starting place.